# How to log an exception type in a separate column with Serilog in ASP.Net Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

Is there a way to log an exception type in a separate column with Serilog in ASP.Net Core application? For what it's worth we use .Net Core 3.1

When logging to SQL Server database table there is a default column called "Exception" but it contains a lot of information, including call stack.

What I would like to have is a separate column with just exception type, like "NotImplementedException" or "ArgumentNullException" and nothing else.

I understand I probably need to use enrichers but not sure how in this case.

Comment: Q: Did you figure out how to change the default schema to add your extra column?  Q: Were you able to do this with Serilog "configuration", or did you subclass your own "Sink"?  Or did you find a completely different solution?

Comment: @FoggyDay: changing schema is describe here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver (I already knew about it). I haven't actually done anything about putting exception type in extra column - will get back to this in about a week.

Answer (score 1):

SUGGESTION:

[Use the source, Luke](https://wiki.c2.com/?UseTheSourceLuke).

1. Download the source Serilog source from GitHub: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver
2. See how [MSSqlServerSink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/Sinks/MSSqlServer/MSSqlServerSink.cs) works.
3. Best case, there's a "configurable" you can leverage (e.g. "columnOptions" or "MessageTemplate").
4. Otherwise, you should be able to subclass MSSqlServerSink with your own, custom sink that has the schema you want.
5. See, too, 
   [serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/sample/CustomLogEventFormatterDemo](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/tree/dev/sample/CustomLogEventFormatterDemo)